# Sprity installation is not successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Should be a module `sprity-lwip` installation is not successful, Installation `sprity-lwip` is alone or not

[The picture of the error, I can't upload pictures](http://sfault-image.b0.upaiyun.com/243/202/2432020387-557edab82c6ee)

npm install `sprity-lwip`

[The picture of the error](http://sfault-image.b0.upaiyun.com/186/454/1864546992-557edad5315a1)

---

> Installation of this module involves compiling native code. If npm install lwip failes, you probably need to setup your system. See instructions. Building on Windows with Visual Studio requires version 2013 or higher.

How to set up my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracted from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprity-lwip

> **Requirements**
>
> `sprity version >= 1.0`

So, you should try this:

`npm install sprity -g`

and no need to install `sprity-lwip` stand alone (I think it is not possible anyway) because it is already included on `sprity` package as you can read here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprity-lwip

> **Install**
>
> `By default sprity-lwip is installed with sprity.`

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I am in the process of installing `sprity` error, so we try to install `sprity-lwip`, you can open the link I see the picture, I can't upload pictures.